# Node.js application restarts when playing large video over HTTPS, works fine with HTTP

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, nginx-reverse-proxy, haproxy

I have a Node.js application that simply plays a video with a size of 521MB. I have used Nginx and HAProxy separately as reverse proxies. When I connect via HTTPS, the page restarts itself after approximately 120-140 seconds once the video starts playing. However, I don't encounter any issues when using the same systems with HTTP. I am stuck and unsure how to proceed.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name SERVERNAME;
location / {
#return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
proxy_pass      http://nodeapp;
}
}

upstream nodeapp {
keepalive 32;
server localhost:3000;
}
server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
server_name SERVERNAME;
ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/privkey.pem;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2; # Requires nginx >= 1.13.0 else use TLSv1.2
ssl_session_timeout  30m;
access_log /var/log/nginx/laccess.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
location / {
      proxy_pass      http://nodeapp;
      proxy_buffering off;
}
}
```

Comment: can you please add your nginx config and haproxy backend configs to your original post?

Comment: I already deleted haproxy config. But before delete I tested and I saw same issue. @AlexD.

Comment: i don't have the possibility to test things out but at a first glance I'd say to comment out ssl timeout and proxy buffer. And does your http server also have keepalive 32?